# If There Is 2 Version In Play Store, How To Download An App's Other Version

Tags: google-play-store

If there are 2 version in any App's Play store console (for 2.3 and 4.0), how can I download 2.3 version in my Android 4.0+ device?

Comment: You're probably going to need to find that .apk from some third party location

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow If I can find 2 version of app in there, yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

**No. You cannot do that directly**. Playstore will automatically detect your Android version and gives your Most suitable version. In your case, You cannot download 2.3 version directly to your phone. However there are otherways to get that

- **Find a device with Android 3.0 or less**. Download & Install  the app from Playstore. Use apps like 'ES File manager'(Or similar apps) **to get the apk of your app, Transfer via *Bluetooth* & Install on your Android 4.0 device**
- Download & Install **Android  2.3 Emulator on your Computer** & Follow the same steps above.
- Use **www.4shared.com or Torrents or Third party app stores** To download apk of the specific version of the app.

Comment: Is there any way to show my device as Android 2.3? (Rooted)